# Don't show the chat welcome overlay on the chat login page

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, chat

Whenever I need to log into chat again for whatever reason (cookie deleted), I'm confronted with this massive banner on the login page which makes me click on some pointlessly small, greyed out text so I can then go click on the actual button to log in.

[image]

Why is that banner even there?  That information isn't really "optional" like the "You have 1 favorite change..." banner that's currently gracing this page as I drone on about this, it is relevant to the log in process.  Why even bother putting that information in a banner?  It's not like the login page is short on space.

Sure, the banner appears on any page you visit on `chat.stackexchange.com` while not logged in, but this is the first one where you actually need to deal with it to continue on.  I can easily join a room before then (it's white on white), then only notice it to be irritated by it when I need to log in.

Remove the banner.  Or at least make it less annoying like the ones on the SE sites proper.  You could start by removing irrelevant things like telling me to check the FAQ.

Comment: That banner is displayed because it is thinking of you as an arbitrary drive-by anonymous user; checking the FAQ, then, is surely not irrelevant?

Comment: I also use a cookie-limited browser sometimes.  That banner is really annoying.  I don't agree that any of it is irrelevant to a cookie-less user, but I agree that it should not be in that banner format which obscures the rest of the page.

Comment: @marc we suppress the "see the faq!" notification on the /users/login page -- chat should too (although I agree chat has no *explicit* login page, the above screenshot is not desirable).